# Selecting the max columns after group by in SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark-SQL in Databricks. I have a dataset like this (but with way more features):

```
Country | ID | feature_1 | feature_2 | feature_3 | feature_4
US       123     100         5          40           60
US       456     200         30          9           70
CA       789     50          12         45           90
CA       999     250         180        17           40
```

I'm interested in knowing which features are the top 3 (i.e. max values) for each country, id grouping, like this:

```
Country |  ID   |    max_1   |   max_2   |   max_3
US         124     feature_1    feature_4   feature_3
US         456     feature_1    feature_4   feature_2
CA         789     feature_4    feature_1   feature_3
CA         999     feature_1    feature_2   feature_4
```

I was thinking of using a `row_number()` window function, but not quite sure how to rank across columns to capture the top 3. Anyone have any ideas? Would I need to `unpivot` the data to do this? (I also need to make this dynamic since I have tons of features)

Comment: `UNPIVOT` can really only handle one "feature" (as you are describing your data here) at a time. You'd need one `UNPIVOT` per feature, then to `JOIN` them, then `PIVOT` them back.  I wouldn't bother with `ROW_NUMBER()`, just a `TOP 3` somewhere after the `UNPIVOT`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. how would i then select the max 3 features columns across all feature columns?

Comment: I just said. You'll need to have a separate UNPIVOT-TOP 3-PIVOT sequence for each and every feature and then JOIN them together. It's going to be unwieldy.